# How to Copy Files From Docker Ubuntu Container to Windows Host

Tags: docker

I can't figure out how to copy files from a docker ubuntu container to a windows host, or vice versa.

My host is Windows 10. When I start Docker, I run the Ubuntu image using

```
docker run -it ubuntu bash
```

The documentation I've read says that the way the transfer files is with `docker cp`, but apparently that command doesn't exist in this ubuntu image, i.e., `bash: docker: command not found`.

This must be a dumb oversight on my part. Can someone please give me a little help?

Comment: You run the command from the host, not the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run docker cp command on host machine.

The command template is:

```
docker cp <containerId>:<src_path_inside_container> <target_host_path>
```